# Why is the string in the Label property of an AppResult not queryable through Property("label")?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

When I query with

```
app.Query(c=>c.Marked("02_Voided_NotReviewed"))
```

I get this result:

```
[[0] {Id => null, Description => 
"md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.FormsImageView{d0c6be9 V.ED..... 
........ 0,0-80,80}",
Rect => {Width => 80, Height => 80, X => 0, Y => 718, CenterX => 40, CenterY 
=> 758}, 
Label => "02_Voided_NotReviewed", 
Text => null, 
Class => "md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.FormsImageView",
Enabled => true }, ...
```

My first confusion is that the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Marked/) for `Marked` doesn't mention it searches the `Label` property for android. So I think it should be returning 0 results, but now to the main issue. I want to use `Property` so I can filter more general results but i'm querying the exact string for simplicity.

When I query with

```
app.Query(c=>c.Property("label").Contains("02_Voided_NotReviewed"))
```

I get 0 results. I've tried `Property("Label")` and `Property("label")`. `Contains`, `StartsWith`, and `Like` also return 0 results. When I use `Property("text")` and query for a string in the Text property I do get results, So I think it's something to do with the `label` property. Has anyone else experience this issue or can see anything i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation you linked](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Marked/) to says that the `Marked` method

> Matches common values. For Android: An element with the given value as either `id`, `contentDescription` or `text`.

It's not immediately apparent, but the `Label` property that you see in UITest is mapped to the Android element's `contentDescription` so this should work:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Property("contentDescription").Contains("02_Voided_NotReviewed"))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I can't believe it was a misunderstanding of what `contentDescription` was referring to. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
App.Query(x => x.Marked("02_Voided_NotReviewed")).FirstOrDefault().Label;
```

it will give you string

```
02_Voided_NotReviewed
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Generally it's better to give a little description with your answer to explain how and why it addresses the original question, and any ways in which it differs from answers that have already been given, to help readers decide between which answer is most appropriate for them.

Comment: Hey Atul, that would be a simpler solution if I was looking for that exact string. I mentioned above I was using the exact string to simplify debugging but I needed to use `Contains` because I was looking for all items that matched a subset of the values represented in the string. (e.g querying for all items that contained "Voided_NotReviewed" in their label) I hope that clarifies why I used `contentDescription`  instead of `Marked`